# How do I recover my lost extensions on Chrome Windows 8.0?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome-extensions

I deleted the Chrome ID on my Laptop and all my Extensions and saved Tabs data, history etc... all just disappeared. I spent weeks on getting those extensions right. Is there a way to recover the lost extensions?

Answer (score -1):

If You have a registered account, You just need to log in and all your saves will be restored.

Else

If You have a windows backup, try doing a system restore.

Or

You can also try to follow [these](http://www.howtogeek.com/111784/how-to-recover-accidentally-deleted-bookmarks-in-chrome-firefox/) steps.